# Typescript Generics - Keep inference when typing object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an issue when using a generic type with default arguments where I lose the benefit of inference if the variable is declared with the generic type.

Given the following types:

```js
type Attributes = Record<string, any>;

type Model<TAttributes extends Attributes = Attributes> = {
  attributes: TAttributes;
};

function create<TModels extends Record<string, Model>>(
  schemas: TModels
): TModels {
  return schemas;
}
```

If I type objects using `Model`, and then pass that object into my generic function, I lose the inference benefit I get if I were to *not* type the object. It works as expected if the generics argument is passed into the `Model` type. As seen here:

```js
const TodoWithGeneric: Model<{ name: string; finished: string }> = {
  attributes: {
    name: "string",
    finished: "boolean"
  }
};

const TodoWithoutGeneric: Model = {
  attributes: {
    name: "string",
    finished: "boolean"
  }
};

const withInference = create({
  Todo: { attributes: { name: "string", finished: "boolean" } }
});
const withGenericsPassed = create({ Todo: TodoWithGeneric });
const withoutAttributesPassedToGeneric = create({
  Todo: TodoWithoutGeneric
});
```

Is there a TypeScript workaround to still have the benefit of typing the declaration of the object, *without* having to pass in generic arguments, yet keep the benefit of no-typing/inference once it's passed into a function?

Ideally, we would have the typescript support on the declaration for `TodoWithoutGeneric`, but by the time it is passed into `withoutAttributesPassedToGeneric`, we strip off the `Model` type and allow inference to take over.

The combined snippets in this question are setup in this sandbox:
[**Code Sandbox here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-bush-qmkxkx?file=/src/index.ts)

The `withInference.Todo.attributes.` and `withGenericsPassed.Todo.attributes.` have the attribute keys available, whereas the `withoutAttributesPassedToGeneric.Todo.attributes` (typed with generic) does not.

Thank you!

Comment: updated with full code in the original & slightly simplified reproducible version

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpQZgW) meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz it does! brilliant use of `satisfies`  - if you post it as a separate answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) a variable with a (non-[union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)) type like `Model`,

```
const TodoWithoutGeneric: Model = ⋯;
```

then that's all the compiler knows about the type of the variable.  It has been widened all the way to `Model`.  Any specific information about the initializer has been discarded.  So if you need to retain more specific information, you can't annotate the type like this.

Presumably you just want to be sure that `TodoWithoutGeneric` *satisfies* the `Model` type without actually widening it to that type.  If so, you can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator):

```
const TodoWithoutGeneric = {
    attributes: {
        name: "string",
        finished: "boolean"
    }
} satisfies Model;
```

You'll still get an error if the initializer doesn't conform to `Model`, but now the type of `TodoWithoutGeneric` is the more specific type

```
/* const TodoWithoutGeneric: {
    attributes: {
        name: string;
        finished: string;
    };
} */
```

And the rest of your code behaves as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAgswCcCWAjArsCBnKBeKAShAMYD2CAJgDxaJIB2A5gDRQCG9IAfANwCwAKEGhIUALKkKEADZUAKnDrpMOCAA9M9CjkXJl2PLHh6M2LoYDegqDfbHUprAC4oC+-qz8BAXy+CAZmj0xMBIpPRQxAgQbJjyElLSqhoQWjhEZJQ0dEysCTJcXAAU1rZYxAAWEAC2bM6u+UmCAJQuco04VgK2UNHAaAgR5VW1noLegpMCZPS0rpKkAOpIwBUA4qkQyMQujVQWUPRs1RAutMhMPFD+DEhYVRRnOYxQ3ub4XT2xSo4unz22I4nFwAInODEYIOYpQB11u9wgjygIJQpFI0hi9BBMNe4z803CczkC2Wq1IGA29C2SGIlhx3xMKj+OJ6QNOyPBTChLNsN3odweoNR6Mx2O6tgmPigWFidxuBka+IA9AAqSKE4DzChLFYVcnASnUnZQf42BkOJkmnk2NlPC6MLywmx8gWIu0Qx0SrzeKAqpVTGZzADuuoAkvR-FtUsRoPgojFMEVTVrSH87D9LQdbRznlC4fyEUiUWiMRwQa9cT5ml5A5qQ6tDdssAAFOpYRGGeOxCBJlNtEm6xs017VwS1qD1vUYXQW7CtrDtijEoe0uPRbtJnHE7X97WkqcGzbbcajgRAA)